# How to Fill a DataSet with TableMapping instead of TableName

Tags: c#

According to msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ks92fwwh.aspx

> The DataTableMapping name can be
>   passed in place of the DataTable name
>   to the Fill method of the DataAdapter.

The code below is with TableName "Employee"

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;     
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data.OleDb;

public class MyClass
{
    public static void Main()
    {
    OleDbConnection mySqlConnection =new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\data\nwind.Mdb");

    OleDbCommand mySqlCommand = mySqlConnection.CreateCommand();
    mySqlCommand.CommandText = "SELECT EmployeeID, FirstName, LastName " +
      "FROM Employees AS Emp " +
      "WHERE EmployeeID = 9";
    OleDbDataAdapter mySqlDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    mySqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand = mySqlCommand;
    DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();

    DataTableMapping myDataTableMapping = mySqlDataAdapter.TableMappings.Add("Employees", "dtEmployee");

    Console.WriteLine("myDataTableMapping.DataSetTable = " + myDataTableMapping.DataSetTable);
    Console.WriteLine("myDataTableMapping.SourceTable = " + myDataTableMapping.SourceTable);

    myDataTableMapping.ColumnMappings.Add("EmployeeID", "dtEmployeeId");
    mySqlConnection.Open();
    mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "Employee");
    mySqlConnection.Close();    

    DataTable myDataTable = myDataSet.Tables["dtEmployee"];
    foreach (DataRow myDataRow in myDataTable.Rows)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("ID = " + myDataRow["dtEmployeeId"]);
      Console.WriteLine("FirstName = " + myDataRow["FirstName"]);
      Console.WriteLine("LastName = " + myDataRow["LastName"]);
    }   
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

}
```

If I pass "dtEmployee" in Fill

```
mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "dtEmployee");
```

It says dtEmployeeId doesn't belong to datatable dtEmployee !
How can I use my ColumnMappings then ?

Comment: what if you try to use just "FROM Employees" instead of "FROM Employees AS Emp" - you're never using that alias - does it work without it, maybe?

Comment: I remove the alias nothing changes

Comment: Just to check, the above code, with `Fill(myDataSet, "Employee")` is working? Then the foreach loop says the column mapping is working.

Comment: Yes column mapping is working but why it doesn't work anymore when I pass dtEmployee which is the table mapping name.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have your arguments in the wrong order. From the MSDN document:

> The following example creates a DataTableMapping named *AuthorsMapping*
>   for the *Authors* table.

```
workAdapter.TableMappings.Add("AuthorsMapping", "Authors");
```

I looks like you're creating a DataTableMapping named *Employees* for the *dtEmployee* table. Try:

```
DataTableMapping myDataTableMapping = mySqlDataAdapter.TableMappings.Add("dtEmployee", "Employees");
```

---

To clarify, right now you're creating a Mapping called *Employees*. You are then filling the DataTable called *dtEmployee*. Since `dtEMployeeId` is on your mapping `Employees` and not your datatable `dtEmployee` it is throwing the right error "dtEmployeeId doesn't belong to **datatable** dtEmployee"